# Partitions created after installation is readonly

Tags: partitioning

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. During installation I give only a single partition. After that I created two more partitions using gparted, but the new partitions are totally useless that I cannot create a new folder or any other tasks like that.

I tried to edit the permissions, but its showing message like only a root user can do it.So feeling exhausted I reverted it back to single partition again.Can someone  me with this. I need to create two useful partitions.

Comment: Are they are ext4 partitions?

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes ext4

Comment: What's the output of `mount` and `cat /etc/fstab`?

Answer (score 2):

To have partitions mounted in read/write mode, you need to change the mount options in `/etc/fstab` and make sure your user has read/write access to the place where the partitions are mounted (the mount point).

1. Get the UUID of your partitions by running `blkid` in a terminal. The output will look something like this (this is on my system, your details will be different):

   ```
   /dev/sda1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="DellUtility" UUID="3030-3030" TYPE="vfat" 
   /dev/sda2: LABEL="RECOVERY" UUID="E208CFC008CF9249" TYPE="ntfs" 
   /dev/sda3: LABEL="OS" UUID="C0BCD19CBCD18D72" TYPE="ntfs" 
   /dev/sda5: LABEL="READER" UUID="4C2D-395C" TYPE="vfat" 
   /dev/sda8: UUID="7696fff5-139c-425f-b3c1-5a3e2ba1158d" TYPE="swap" 
   /dev/sda6: LABEL="Home" UUID="a180cec0-ecad-4944-8e29-7c9249ed23b0" TYPE="ext4" 
   /dev/sda7: UUID="d5cf136f-f344-4187-92c5-e29c6006c5c6" TYPE="ext4"
   ```

   Note the UUID of your partition (eg. `a180cec0-ecad-4944-8e29-7c9249ed23b0` and it's type, eg. `ext4`), you will need these to modify fstab.
2. Create the mount point for these partitions, the place where you want them to be accessible. For example, `/media/data1` and `/media/data2`, and change their permissions to give everyone read/write access to your user:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /media/data1 /media/data2
   sudo chmod a+wrx  /media/data1 /media/data2
   ```
3. Let's say you want sda6 and sda7 to be mounted read/write. Open `/etc/fstab` as root:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/fstab
   ```
4. Add these lines to the file:

   ```
   ## sda6
   UUID=a180cec0-ecad-4944-8e29-7c9249ed23b0   /media/data1    ext4    defaults    0   0
   ## sda7
   UUID=d5cf136f-f344-4187-92c5-e29c6006c5c6   /media/data2    ext4    defaults    0   0
   ```

   **IMPORTANT**: make sure you change the UUID above to the one returned by `blkid` and the `ext4` to whatever `TYPE` was for that partition.
5. Either reboot (they will now be mounted automatically) or run `sudo mount -a`. You should now have read write access to both partitions at `/media/data1` and `/media/data2`.

Comment: Too complicated...

Comment: @DušanMilosevic perhaps but 1) it actually works 2) it won't break your system 3) it will persist after reboot 4) is the right way® to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to change the ownership of your single ext4 partition.From the single partition again create two new ext4 partitions, like you did before.Then mount the newly created ext4 partitions.After that, change the ownership of the mounted partitions(*which are newly created*) from `root` to `$USER`.

Try the below commad to change the ownership of the mounted partition from `root` to `$USER`,

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER /media/xxxx
```

`/media/xxxx` - Represents the location where your ext4 partition is mounted.

By default for a newly created ext4 partition, owner must be root.You have to change it to `$USER`, so that you can  access the mounted partition in read write mode.

Answer (score 0):

I for a few mins ago answerd kinda the same question: If the FS is NTFS:

```
ntfsfix /dev/yourdisk
```

Hopefully this helps someone in the future, if it dosen't leave a comment and I can try to help you,

Regards.